# Selecting users from orders where all orders has the state "errored"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-console

Sorry if the question is confusing, because I'm not sure on how to ask the question, but here I go:

I'm inside the rails console trying to find all users with orders where all orders has the state "errored", and ONLY errored. A user has many orders, and the order state on each of them can differ from "completed", "refunded" or "errored".

```
User.includes(:orders).where(orders: { state: "errored" })
```

This is returning all users who has one or more errored orders as it's suppose to, whether or not the user have orders with other states as well. But I'm trying to fetch the users who **ONLY** has errored orders.

I've tried a lot of things, from iterating through every order in every user, to trying to manually find them. But it got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My SQL isn't what it used to be but I believe that for a pure SQL solution it would need to look something like:

```
SELECT  "users".*
  FROM "users"
  LEFT JOIN orders on orders.user_id = users.id
  LEFT JOIN orders non_errored_orders on non_errored_orders.user_id = users.id and non_errored_orders.state <> 'errored'
  WHERE "non_errored_orders"."id" IS NULL AND "orders"."id" IS NOT NULL
```

So, we left join the `orders` table with the alias `non_errored_orders` and that will make it so that if there is an order where the user id matches and the state is not equal to *errored*, a row will appear (and `non_errored_orders.id` will end up as `NOT NULL`). In the `where` clause we then filter down to only users whose `non_errored_orders.id IS NULL`, filtering out all users who matched an order that was not *errored*.

We then left join the `orders` table again with no alias only matching on `users.id = orders.user_id`. If there is no `orders.id`, that means the user does not have any orders in the table at all, so we want to filter down to only users where `orders.user_id IS NOT NULL`, meaning they had an order.

You can do a query like this in rails by doing something like:

```ruby
User.
  joins(:orders).
  joins("LEFT JOIN orders non_errored_orders on non_errored_orders.user_id = users.id and non_errored_orders.state <> 'errored'").
  where(non_errored_orders: { id: nil }).
  where.not(orders: { id: nil }).distinct
#  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT JOIN orders non_errored_orders on non_errored_orders.user_id = users.id and non_errored_orders.state <> 'errored' WHERE "non_errored_orders"."id" IS NULL AND ("orders"."id" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, ...>]>
```

In my very limited test set this seems to be working.

*test data was*

```ruby
User.find(1).orders.create([ { state: 'errored' }, { state: 'errored' } ])
User.find(2).orders.create([ { state: 'errored' }, { state: 'completed' }])
User.find(3).orders.create([ { state: 'refunded' } ])
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, really learned something new here! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about little long but simplified path?

```
users_with_other_order_states = User.join(:orders).where.not(orders: { state: "errored" }).pluck(:id)

User.joins(:orders).where('orders.state = "errored" AND users.id NOT IN (?)', users_with_other_order_states)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving this a shot. I got errors trying to use your simplified path, I fixed the typos but it still didn't work. It gives me this message: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "912"
LINE 1: ...ERE (orders.state = "errored" AND users.id NOT IN 912,25,123...

But anyways, one of the answers below got the solution. So thank you anyway for giving it a shot.

Comment: Just updated the solution. The error was coming due to SQL syntax error. Changed `?` with `(?)`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try define an `errored_orders` relation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many errored_orders, ->{where state: 'errored'}
end

User.includes(:errored_orders).where(...)
```

Hope it helps!